# My Gallery Photos are showing in the post's excerpts

Tags: post-thumbnails, gallery

I just can't win with this project! All of a sudden, each post's gallery photos are showing up in the excerpt/preview of the post. Each post has a gallery of images that should only be visible on the actual post's page. Can anyone see what might be causing this?

Here is my code:

```
if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) {
     the_post_thumbnail();
}
else {
     get_the_image( array('size' => 'thumbnail',
                          'image_class' => 'wp-post-image'));   
}
```

Then in my functions file:

```
// This theme displays custom size (page-single) featured image on the Post's  page

function InsertFeaturedImage($content) {

    global $post;

    $original_content = $content;

    if ( current_theme_supports( 'post-thumbnails' ) ) {

        if ((is_page()) || (is_single())) {

            $content = get_the_image( array( 'size' => 'full' ) );
            $content .= $original_content;
        }
    }
    return $content;
}

add_filter( 'the_content', 'InsertFeaturedImage' );
```

You can view the site in question here:  http://dependablecarcompany.com

You'll see the horribly broken site in question. There should only be the ONE excerpt representative thumbnail there, and not all the thumbs from the gallery too.

Thank You!

Comment: Thank you for your reply peter! I'm trying to use this, but I'm getting a syntax error, now. I will keep trying to figure it out though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
   if(  ( is_page() || is_single() ) && ( !is_home() &&  !is_front_page() )  ){
        $content = strip_shortcodes( $original_content); 
    }
```

**if its home or front page don't show gallery**

```
    if( is_home() || is_front_page() ) {
          // don't show gallery
          $content = strip_shortcodes( $original_content); 
    } else {
          $content = get_the_image( array( 'size' => 'full' ) );
          $content .= $original_content;
    }
```

The post was using shorttags to print the gallery, `get_the_image()` printed the thumbnail.

so by removing the shorttags from appearing in the front page, the gallery no longer is shown on it, but will show on other pages, and also, **categories**, **tags** etc.

To further improve on that, add `|| is_archive()` to the conditional above.

reference for [is_home()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_home) and [strip_shortcodes()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/strip_shortcodes)

---

just for fun:

**truth table:**

0 0 0 1 = ( 0 || 0 ) && ( 1 && 0 ) = 0 && 1 = 0

0 0 1 0 = ( 0 || 0 ) && ( 0 && 1 ) = 0

0 0 1 1 = 0

0 1 0 0 = 0

... = 0

1 0 0 0 = 1

0 1 0 0 = 1

1 1 0 0 = 1

... = 0

Comment: Is there a way to say if is_home or if is_front_page then don't display the gallery thumbnails?

Comment: yes, more or less, but yes. i've updated the response.

Comment: dangit! haha, I can't get anything to work without throwing syntax errors. Should I be trying to combine both of those code blocks together as one?  In other words, do I combine the is_single is_home code block with the new is_font_page is_home code you just posted?  Thanks!

Comment: there you go, all nice and done ;)

Comment: Thanks a ton for your time peter! Just doesn't fix the problem though. So weird. I've tried so many things and the stupid gallery photos are showing on the home page no matter what. I appreciate you trying though.

Comment: i've been assuming that `$content = get_the_image( array( 'size' => 'full' ) );` is the part that prints the gallery, but re-reading, i could be wrong?

Comment: Well that part of it has to do with the Get Image plugin by Justin Tadlock, which automatically picks an image if no Featured Image is chosen. I did this so that my client won't have to manually pick a Featured Image everytime.  I was thinking that this problem HAS to be because of this part of the code and the plugin itself, but I've disabled the plugin and took out this part of the code, and the home page is still all screwed up. It just doesn't make sense. It was working fine. I can't see what broke.

Comment: i that case, i see whats the problem. its much easier than we though! i've updated the response.

Comment: Holy Crap! You are the man! That did it! I'm sure you are busy, but is there anyway you can explain how that fixed it? I'm sorry. I HAVE to start learning PHP! I'm really curious what was breaking this. No problem if it's too much to explain here though.

Comment: i've posted a small explanation about what was happening. glad its working for you now!

Answer (score 0):

Myers.

I guess you have this code on your index.php file or whathever file displaying content in homepage:

```
if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) {
 the_post_thumbnail(); 
} else {
 get_the_image( array('size' => 'thumbnail',
                      'image_class' => 'wp-post-image'));   
}
```

I had tested in mine. I do not use the code above. I only use this in functions.php

```
// This theme displays custom size (page-single) featured image on the Post's  page

function InsertFeaturedImage($content) {

global $post;

$original_content = $content;

if ( current_theme_supports( 'post-thumbnails' ) ) {

    if ((is_page()) || (is_single())) {

        $content = get_the_image( array( 'size' => 'full' ) );
        $content .= $original_content;
    }
}
return $content; 
}
add_filter( 'the_content', 'InsertFeaturedImage' );
```

Comment: Thanks for your recommendation. It still does the same thing though. I don't want any of the gallery thumbs to show at all, on the home page.